# Assigning an account to user, Acknowledgement Mail is not sending- Suite CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

An email has to send to the user when he was assigned to an account in suitecrm. But the mail is not sending and i have checked the log, it shows,

> SugarPHPMailer encountered an error: The outbound mail server selected
>   for the mail account you are using is invalid.  Check the settings or
>   select a different mail server for the mail account. SugarPHPMailer
>   encountered an error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I have tried the 'Test mail' in the admin/ Email settings and i got the test mail.

Can you please help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have some issues similar to this on SugarCRM 7.7 as well. I seem to get some success with testing then saving, then trying the assignment email again.

Comment: I could fix this issue. I just commented the SMTP section in sugarPHPMailer.php. Please refer this link, [link](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/1123)